# how to use prefillPhonenuber in account kit in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, account

I am using accountkit for passwordless login and I want to use prefillphonenumber but when I am sending string app crash and I am getting

> [__NSCFConstantString phoneNumber]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a84f0e0

How to use preFillPhoneNumber ?

Comment: can you show your crashed code

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using this API

```
/*!
 @abstract Returns a view controller to be presented to initiate a phone login.

 @param phoneNumber the phone number to be used for login.
 @param state the state for the login request.
 */
- (UIViewController<AKFViewController> *)viewControllerForPhoneLoginWithPhoneNumber:(nullable AKFPhoneNumber *)phoneNumber
                                                                              state:(nullable NSString *)state;
```

If so, make sure that you are creating a `PhoneNumber` object, and not passing a string directly. Something like:

```
AKFPhoneNumber *phoneNumber = [[AKFPhoneNumber alloc] initWithCountryCode:@"+1" phoneNumber:@"123456789"];
UIViewController *vc = [_accountKit viewControllerForPhoneLoginWithPhoneNumber:phoneNumber];
...
```

From the error it seems like you may be passing a string instead. Xcode should detect that as an error unless you are specifically casting it with `(id)`